# In GCP face detection, where should we assume to be the axis to measure the roll angle?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, face-detection, euler-angles, vision-api

I need to rotate images of faces. I want to understand the output of GCP face detection. For the roll angle,  where is the axis supposed to be? at the mouth center? at the nose? at the bottom left of the image file?

The definition of roll angle is here: http://www.conitec.net/beta/aentity-pan.htm
GCP explanation of the output seems to be in this outdated page: https://developers.google.com/vision/face-detection-concepts
Here it seems the z-axis is located at the lower left corner, which cannot be if we want to be precise. To get the image with that rotation we will need the axis to be located in the head.

---

Update: I have been told that the rotation is with respect to the center of the image. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/face-tutorial) is the GCP service for [Face Detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/other-features#faces) (**let me point out that this feature doesn't support Facial Recognition**). You can refer to this similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53145594/can-google-cloud-vision-api-label-faces) that contains additional information about Google Cloud Vision API where it may be helpful to better understand this feature.

As mentioned, in case this feature doesn't cover your current needs, you can use the Send Feedback button, located at the lower left and upper right corners of the service [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-faces), as well as take a look at the [Issue Tracker tool](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) in order to raise a [Vision API feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1010433) and notify Google about this desired functionality.

Comment: I wrote careless, I meant to ask about face detection. I updated my question, thanks.